# grails mongo sort query with key as variable

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

i have this code (grails):

```
println sortField
println sortType
domainProfileList = db.getCollection("domainProfile").find(["location.value.city" : ['$in' : location]], ["_id" : 1]).sort([sortField : sortType])
```

now this part has the problem:

```
.sort([sortField : sortType])
```

key sortField is taken by mongo as it is ( i.e. its rendered as sortField not the value present in sortField , where as sortType is rendered fine as 1 or -1 )

what is the correct syntax in grails to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

please use like this:

```
.sort(["${sortField}" : sortType])
```

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String getting this error